# Reading a .CSV file in C

Tags: c, csv

I'm going back to C at my University a year of Java, and our first assignment is to read the values present in a .CSV file, but the textbook isn't clear and the prof hasn't helped us much. I really don't have a lot of direction on this, and the assignment is due soon, so I really need some direction!

I think I can get through most everything myself, but I'm just not certain what this block of code does...

```
static int extractItems(char *line, char row[][MAXLEN]) {
    char *item;
    int col = 0;
    for( ; ; ) {
        item = strtok(line, ",\r\n");
        if (item == NULL)
            break;
        if (col >= MAXCOLS) {
            tooWide = 1;
            break;
        }
        strncpy(row[col], item, MAXLEN);
        row[col][MAXLEN] = '\0'; // force null termination
        col++;
        line = NULL;  // required by strtok function
    }
    return col;
}
```

Col refers to the column number, the first being 0.

I understand that it checks if there is nothing in the line and whether it's too wide, but the rest is foreign to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to explain is to comment the code:

```
static int extractItems(char *line, char row[][MAXLEN]) {
                                      //line is a char* to your array of chars
                                                     // - one long string
                                      //row is a two dimensional array of chars
                                                     // - an array of strings
    char *item;
    int col = 0;
    for( ; ; ) {                      //infinite loop, we can exit it with "break" though
        item = strtok(line, ",\r\n"); //string->token.  Returns a pointer to a string,
                                      //which is the next token in the input.
                                      //it does this by replacing the first character found 
                                      //from the second string passed (",\r\n") with '\0'
                                      //and returning the pointer to where it started 
                                      //searching from.
                                      //i.e. it cuts the string up into substings (tokens)
                                      //and returns a pointer to the next one each time 
                                      //it is called.
        if (item == NULL)             //if NULL we are at end of the line. so exit loop
            break;
        if (col >= MAXCOLS) {         //if we have read too much (reached our limit) then exit
            tooWide = 1;              //is this a global? anyway it is used to signal that there was too much data
            break;
        }
        strncpy(row[col], item, MAXLEN); //copy the temporary string returned by strtok to the array
        row[col][MAXLEN] = '\0';      // force null termination (C_string remember?)
        col++;                        // increment the number of words counted
        line = NULL;                  // required by strtok function
                                          //passing in NULL gets strtok to continue scanning
                                          //from the end of the previous successful scan
    }
    return col;
}
```

for more info on strtok: [this answer describes it well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21097376/4022608)

Answer (score 0):

Lets break the program and analyse,

```
static int extractItems(char *line, char row[][MAXLEN]) {
```

`line` is an array which contains the current line being read from the CSV file.
`row` is a two dimentional array where each item is a individual element from the CSV file

```
 item = strtok(line, ",\r\n");
```

strtok function splits the string, first argument, here `line` into tokens based on the deliminter string, second argument, here `,\n\r`
That is if the CSV file contains a line  
`Hello, world`
then subsiquent calls to strtok with the line, produces
`Hello` => split line at ,
`world` => split line at \n, \r is used in windows as newline 
[For further reading refer this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html)

Now the individual elements are obtained in `item` which is copied on to the `row` by the `strncpy` which copies n, MAXLEN characters.

```
strncpy(row[col], item, MAXLEN); 
row[col][MAXLEN] = '\0';
```

It is then deliminted by `\0`

```
col++;                       
line = NULL;
```

incremennts to the next position for next item and sets `line` to NILL for next.

Since the array `row` is passed by reference as default, once the program is run the `row` will contains each of the comma seperated value in the CSV file.