# How does printf know the end of the tokens of strtok while printing them out?

Tags: c, printf, c-strings, strtok

I'm just trying to figure out what's going on in the background, when I tokenize a c string with strtok and print out the tokens by printf with %s.

So this is the example:

```
char str[] = "Where - is - the - end - of - tokens?";
const char s[2] = "-";
char *token;

/* get the first token */
token = strtok(str, s);

/* walk through other tokens */
while( token != NULL ) {
    printf( " %s\n", token );
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
}

return(0);
```

My beliefs:
- strtok doesn't create a copy of the given c string, just return the memory address of the first character of the given c string.
- printf with %s will print out characters from a memory address until /0.

My question is the following:
How does printf know where to stop printing out characters of a token with %s?

Please help my understand this behaviour of printf with %s.

Comment: Read the docs for strtok again, you only have half the story.

Comment: There's a reason strtok takes a pointer to a mutable buffer

Comment: It replaces every sequence of tokens with --- what? (hint: that's how it knows where the token ends)

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097253/how-does-the-strtok-function-in-c-work

Comment: Change `printf( " %s\n", token );` to `printf( "<t:%s> <s:%s>\n", token, str );` for a more informative output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got my answer what is so simple:
"Each delimiter is replaced by a null character."
Source: [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rtref/strtok.htm)